# highlight different variations of search string

Tags: php, mysql, highlight

i'm using a code which finds similar words also, for example if user searches the word "hello" it also finds the word "hellö"

but when i try to highlight the search string in the results, it only highlights "hello" even though it has found "hellö"

code:

```
$StrSQL = "SELECT `text` FROM `articles` WHERE $strCondition ORDER BY $strOrderBy";


    foreach ($dbh->query($StrSQL) as $row) {
        $text = $row['text'];
        $searchvalue2 = $row['text'];


//to highlight entire unicode word
$searchvalue2 = preg_replace("/\p{L}*?".preg_quote($query)."\p{L}*/ui", "<b>$0</b>", $searchvalue2);
echo "<br>".$searchvalue2."<br>";
```

echo of $strCondition is like this:

```
( REPLACE(text, 'ـ', '') REGEXP 'hell(ö|o|ô)')
```

how can i make it highlight hello hellö and hellô, not just the exact $query.. 
can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 php functions which may help.

[**Soundex**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) is a phonetic algorithm for indexing names by sound, as pronounced in English. And  [**Metaphone**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php) which improves Soundex for English.

You will need to create a separate field to hold to hold this.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i'm already using a method to "find" different variations of the search string, what i can't figure it out is, how can i re-find them to highlight in the results..